# string manipulation in python for reading json object and '' removal

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I am trying to construct a role in AWS where I am trying to have list of resources.

Below is an example

```
shared ={
    "mts":{
        "account_id":"11111",
        "workbench":"aaaaa",
        "prefix":"rad600-ars-sil,rad600-srr-sil-stage1,rad600-srr-sil-stage2"
    },
    "tsf":{
        "account_id":"22222",
        "workbench":"bbbbb",
        "prefix":"yyyy"

    }
}
```

I am trying to construct a list with

```
role_arn=[]
for key in shared:
    
    role_arn.append(f"arn:aws:iam::'{shared[key]['account_id']}':role/'{shared[key]['workbench']}'_role")
```

here is my output:

```
["arn:aws:iam::'11111':role/'aaaaa'_role", "arn:aws:iam::'22222':role/'bbbbb'_role"]
```

I want the `''` to be removed from the list while appending into the list itself.

desired output:

```
["arn:aws:iam::11111:role/aaaaa_role", "arn:aws:iam::22222:role/bbbbb_role"]
```

I am trying my hands on python.
IS there a way to achieve it?

Comment: It is YOU who are inserting those quotes.  It's right there in your string:  `...iam::'{shared[key...`.  If you don't want the single quotes, then remove them before and after the braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
role_arn=[]
for key in shared:
    
    role_arn.append(f"arn:aws:iam::{shared[key]['account_id']}:role/{shared[key]['workbench']}_role")
```

You don't need those `'` unless you want them. You can remove it and the string formatting would still work as expected and get rid of the `'`.

Most likely your concern was coming from not knowing the Lietral format strings. You don't need to use `''`  before every variable. `{}` takes care of it.

Answer (score 1):

#### This is my take on it

This uses dictionary comprehension to iterate over the shared dictionary instead of a for loop

```py
shared ={
    "mts":{
        "account_id":"11111",
        "workbench":"aaaaa",
        "prefix":"rad600-ars-sil,rad600-srr-sil-stage1,rad600-srr-sil-stage2"
    },
    "tsf":{
        "account_id":"22222",
        "workbench":"bbbbb",
        "prefix":"yyyy"

    }
}

role_arn = [f"arn:aws:iam::{data['account_id']}:role/{data['workbench']}_role" for key, data in shared.items()]

print(role_arn)
```

#### Which gives the output

`['arn:aws:iam::11111:role/aaaaa_role', 'arn:aws:iam::22222:role/bbbbb_role']`